# Child records rarely wind up with wrong foreign key using java batch statements / arraylists

Tags: java, mysql

I have an app that logs a lot of data to a database. I write records to a primary table and when necessary, some extra data is then written to a separate table with a foreign key pointing to the primary table.

The dilemma originally was that for performance reasons, the primary table data was written in batches. I had to find a way to write the "child" data after the primary record batches were complete.

However, I'm noticing that in a small percent of cases, **the child records are being written with incorrect foreign keys**. < 5% of the time, they have the wrong parent.

Essentially, code runs through a queue of objects that contain data which will be written to a mysql database:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
s = conn.prepareStatement("insert into ... ");

while( !queue.isEmpty() ){
    SomeObject a = queue.poll();
    s.setString(1,a.someValue);
    // ... etc, prepare 
    extraDataQueue.add( a );
}

s.executeBatch();
insertExtraData( extraDataQueue, s.getGeneratedKeys() );
conn.commit();
```

We have a separate table for extra data that's only needed for 1/3 of the records written to a primary table. The solution I came up with was to keep an array of all objects actually used in writing the data to the primary table.

Then I could match those objects with the returned keys, so I can find the correct foreign key when saving the "extra" data:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param keys
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
protected void insertExtraData( ArrayList<SomeObject> extraDataQueue, ResultSet keys ) throws SQLException{

    if( extraDataQueue.isEmpty() ) return;

    PreparedStatement s = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = Database.conn();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        s = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data_extra ...");
        int i = 0;
        while(keys.next()){

            SomeObject a = extraDataQueue.get(i);

            s.setString(//stuff)
            s.addBatch();

            i++;

        }
        s.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(s != null) try { s.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
        if(conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

The `extraDataQueue` array list was originally a class-level private variable which could have led to some overlap when a lot of data is being recorded so I've moved it to a local variable created new for each time the "queue dump" activates. I hope that will reduce/solve the issue but I'm trying to find out:

- Is there a better way to write child table data when using batches?
- Am I missing something about ArrayLists or returned keys that would produce an alternate order than I'm expecting? I've seen that with HashMaps, but never ArrayLists.

Comment: I have the following comments,  
1. think you should be checking the length of s.getGeneratedKeys() & extraDataQueue and make sure they are same or something similar, how can you be sure that all the records executed successfully?  
2. You are using two different connections in both the methods, i would suggest using the same connection with autocommit set to false

Comment: I've taken out some code for brevity, but I do have a check comparing the lengths. However, all it can do is spit out an error for my users, it really does nothing to help resolve a mismatch

Comment: Is this single threaded?  Or are there ever threads inserting into the primary table at the same time that rows are inserted into the secondary table?

Comment: It's multi-threaded. The main application stores all objects that need to be recorded in a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, and every few seconds fires a recorder task with the first block of logic above - it checks if the queue is non-empty, builds the queries and writes to the db. I have a dev build started that changes this so that the recorder task reschedules itself, that ways there's never two running at once. That's incomplete, but maybe needs to be finished to solve this?